# How can the sum be bigger than itself?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was given a question by my professor and I'm confused on how to start due to the fact that $s_2$ can't be bigger than itself?

You roll a pair of standard fair six-sided dice three times, and record the sum of the two faces showing each time. Let these three sums be $s_1, s_2$, and $s_3$. What is the probability that $s_2$ is strictly bigger than both $s_1$ and $s_2$?

Would the answer be $P(s_2) = 0$ because it can never be strictly bigger than itself?

Comment: Are you sure that there wasn't a typo?  Perhaps you were asked about the probability that $s_3$ is bigger than the two others, no?

Comment: @lulu That is what I am thinking too it must be a typo, but I also thought maybe I was missing something about probability which let the problem make sense.

Comment: As stated,  it is certainly true that the probability that $s_2>s_2$ is $0$.  But, as I said,  I suspect something else was intended.